# AWS: Order of Lifecycle scripts?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use CodeDeploy integrating with my Auto Scaling Group.

My configuration for auto scaling group has user data script to install PHP and etc. And my AfterInstall hook script for CodeDeploy runs a simple php file.

User Data(this works fine)

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install ruby
apt-get -y install wget
cd /home/ubuntu
wget https://aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
./install auto

sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install php7.1 -y
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip php7.1-mbstring php7.1-dom php7.1-curl -y

sudo php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
sudo php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
sudo php composer-setup.php
sudo php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I created a Auto Scaling Group with this Configuration but instances fail to launch with an error that PHP is an unknown command. And I have a few question about this.

I think this is because **AfterInstall hook of Code Deploy was started to execute before my user data script finishes to install PHP. Am I correct?**

If I correct, **how do I fix the order?**

Building an AMI including all requirements pre-installed instead of install everything by user data script, could it be a solution? **What is the best practice?**

Any answer will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a easiest way to fix this myself.

See this article. https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/devops/under-the-hood-aws-codedeploy-and-auto-scaling-integration/

According to this, CodeDeploy Agent starts to get deployment as soon as it's started when launching a new instance.

> **Ordering execution of launch scripts** – The CodeDeploy agent looks for and executes deployments as soon as it starts. There is no ordering between the deployment execution and   launch scripts such as user data, cfn-init, etc. We recommend you install the host agent as part of (and maybe as the last step in) the launch scripts so that you can be sure the deployment won’t be executed until the instance has installed dependencies that are not part of your CodeDeploy deployment. If you prefer baking the agent into the base AMI, we recommend that you keep the agent service in a stopped state and use the launch scripts to start the agent service.

So, I rearranged my user data script in order to install Code Deploy Agent at last after all requirements installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install php7.1 -y
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip php7.1-mbstring php7.1-dom php7.1-curl -y

sudo php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
sudo php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
sudo php composer-setup.php
sudo php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install ruby
apt-get -y install wget
cd /home/ubuntu

wget https://aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
./install auto
```

After this, all work great.